# How to get form.submit response when the client is on another domain?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, post

I  have created a form using javascript, what it does is, it takes customer to another domain with some data, the problem is that while the customer is on another domain it, he approves something and another domain sends me a callback, but i cant recieve it since form.submit is a one way thing.

I have searched around for a bit, but couldnt find any solution.

```
 <script>
 var theAlifForm, newInput1, newInput1,newInput2,newInput3,newInput4,newInput5,newInput6,newInput7;
  // Start by creating a <form>
  theAlifForm = document.createElement('form');
  theAlifForm.action = 'https://alifpay.tj/web';
  theAlifForm.method = 'post';
  // Next create the <input>s in the form and give them names and values
  newInput1 = document.createElement('input');
  newInput1.type = 'hidden';
  newInput1.name = 'token';
  newInput1.id = 'token';
  newInput1.value = "<?php echo  $token;?>";

  newInput2 = document.createElement('input');
  newInput2.type = 'hidden';
  newInput2.name = 'key';
  newInput2.id = 'key';
  newInput2.value = "<?php echo  $a->key;?>";

   newInput3 = document.createElement('input');
  newInput3.type = 'hidden';
  newInput3.name = 'callbackUrl';
  newInput3.id = 'callbackUrl';
  newInput3.value = "<?php echo $a->callbackUrl;?>";

   newInput4 = document.createElement('input');
  newInput4.type = 'hidden';
  newInput4.name = 'returnUrl';
  newInput4.id = 'returnUrl';
  newInput4.value = "<?php echo $a->returnUrl;?>";

    newInput5 = document.createElement('input');
  newInput5.type = 'hidden';
  newInput5.name = 'amount';
  newInput5.id = 'amount';
  newInput5.value = "<?php echo $a->amount;?>";

  newInput6 = document.createElement('input');
  newInput6.type = 'hidden';
  newInput6.name = 'orderId';
  newInput6.id = 'orderId';
  newInput6.value = "<?php echo $a->orderid;?>";

    newInput7 = document.createElement('input');
  newInput7.type = 'hidden';
  newInput7.name = 'info';
  newInput7.id = 'info';
  newInput7.value = "<?php echo $a->info;?>";

  // Now put everything together...
  theAlifForm.appendChild(newInput1);
  theAlifForm.appendChild(newInput2);
  theAlifForm.appendChild(newInput3);
  theAlifForm.appendChild(newInput4);
  theAlifForm.appendChild(newInput5);
  theAlifForm.appendChild(newInput6);
  theAlifForm.appendChild(newInput7);
  console.log(theAlifForm);
document.getElementById('hidden_form_container_custom').appendChild(theAlifForm);
  theAlifForm.submit();

  </script>
```

So how can i recieve a callback since the customer is on another domain at that moment? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are sending them `$a->callbackUrl`, which is the URL to which alifpay is going to redirect the customer after they approved the payment. "Receiving that callback" means you need to set up an endpoint accordingly; like `https://yourdomain/afterpayment`. Create the page in the wordpress dashboard, then handle the POST data in a function in your functions.php that checks if the page is `afterpayment` and proceeds from there.

Comment: Thanks for response, the problem is that they redirect to return url after customer pays but they report the payment status on $a->callbackUrl; and i need to handle it there so no page is being loaded since when they report it the customer is still at their webpage.

Comment: In that case you need to create an AJAX endpoint; the URL is `https://yourdomain/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`. The POST data they send there must contain an `action` though; not sure if that is supported? Is it important that you reply to their POST request? If not, you can still do what I described, you'll get the POST data either way. The fact that you're sending back a page doesn't matter, since they most likely discard the reply anyway.

Comment: I dont need to send them back anything else, the thing is i have to update my system depending on the status of payment. Could you please checkout this example they sent me? Its going to make it clearer. https://github.com/Alif-Capital/sdk

Comment: Right, so where exactly are you stuck? Just put `thank_you.php` in your wordpress folder and give them the URL as callback url. Where it says `echo "Success";` you simply do what their comment says instead: `//update datebase for success payment` I'd love to help you but I don't really know which part you don't understand.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply it got late in our timezone. The thing is i have built and extension for the plugin that ads this payment gateway, and when i upload thank_you.php it simply doesnt recieve a callback. If i put the callback to a page ill have to wait untill the page is going to get loaded so the code is executed right? And the problem is that they send the callback when the customer is still on their page, so i have to some kind of recieve callback as an AJAX response right? The problem is form.submit doesnt recieve a callback. I might have some misunderstanding in process.

Comment: `so i have to some kind of recieve callback as an AJAX response right` not really, no. AJAX means requesting a URL using JavaScript from inside the browser. But I don't think that's what they do, *their server* will request the callback URL when the payment is processed. This means that whatever code you put into thank_you.php will run *on your server* as soon as alifpay processes the payment. So you need to mark the customer's order as *paid* in your database in thank_you.php, if the POST data they sent checks out. There's no direct way to get notified of this, but since the customer gets...

Comment: ...sent back to your website, by the time they get there, your website should show the order as paid, based on the database change caused by alif requesting `thank_you.php`.

Comment: Look at it this way: a PHP script is a program that runs on your server as soon as it is requested by a machine/program somewhere. The script runs, it might do some stuff on the server, then it might send/output some JSON or HTML. Commonly, PHP scripts output HTML and are requested by browsers, that's how you build a website using PHP. But that's just one application; in the end, PHP is just a way to run some commands on a remote computer, and maybe get back a reply.

Comment: Hi. If you could somehow wrap it up and put it as an answer ill approve it.

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't know what to put in the answer.

Comment: Hi Chris, im so sorry to bother you but you are the only person that answered to me so far. I have a simple question that i posted right here https://stackoverflow.com/q/58547204/12006844 if you have any spare time could answer it? Thanks for your time.